# Unlock Huawei BootLoader- Is brute force the only way now?

Tags: bootloader, huawei, bootloader-lock

**Problem**

So I wanna unlock the BootLoader on my Huawei Mate 9 to install LineageOS on it. I already read that Huawei stopped giving BootLoader codes. Is the only way (for free) now, to brute force all possible codes?

**Brute forcing method**

<del>I would write a simple Python script that iterates through all numbers (16 digits) up to 10^16 and performs the corresponding command. My CPU cores have 3 GHz, so it would only take about 55 Minutes (10^16 / 3.000.000.000).</del>


<del>But I don't know if this is possible, how should I check if a device is unlocked using Python? And does the device get locked after a few attempts?</del>

[Here's a script](https://github.com/WilliamWangyueming/bruteforce-bootloader-unlock) made by someone else, it would need too long.

Any advice or help would be appreciated.

Comment: please do a bruteforce with only 10x attempts and measure real time (forget the hardware needed for pressing vol button for now). after this, come back and answer your own question

Comment: Yeah I just read it. I forgot to calculate the time. Do you have an idea?

Comment: buy unlock code from third party seller